# How can I search within documents from the Finder?

Tags: finder, spotlight, search, ocr

I scan documents (receipts, etc) PDFs and the software does OCR to make them searchable. I can search them from within Preview, but I'd like to be able to search within the documents in Finder (or Spotlight). Is there a way to do this? Or a third-party app that does it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a free app, **EasyFind**, that will let you search files. Its available from the app store. It has a fast search engine and you can select where to search. Click the setting button on the top left to select which file extension to search in.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it searches *in* the actual files though. i.e. it doesn't search the text within a PDF

Answer (score 1):

It actually seems like Spotlight already does this. Sorry for the point less question!